# Odd Ratios in SPSS

Tags: odds-ratio

After trying and googling I am unable to calculate Odd Ratios for my data

I would like to mention I know how to calculate Odd ratios for a 2 by 2 table but this time I have different data
I have three age groups, namely: Group A, Group B and Group C
All these groups have two out comes for a disease Yes or No

Group A Yes 18 
 Group B Yes 80
 Group C Yes 110
 Group A No  7
 Group B No 124
 Group C No 110

I have done the Chi Square test and find P value 0.003 (significant)
So I want to calculate the Odd Ratios for this data but unable to calculate please help me with that 
I am using SPSS 
SPSS gives error that

a. Risk Estimate statistics cannot be computed. They are only computed for a 2*2 table without empty cells.

Please help me out with that

Comment: The odds ratios of what compared to what? Do you consider, say, A to be a baseline & want odds ratios for the others compared to that? Or would you want a progression of odds ratios A to B to C to D, eg? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the odds ratio using binary logistic regression analysis in SPSS. Move the outcome variable (Coded: `No=0` and `Yes=1`) to the "Dependent" box and the independent variable (i.e., age category) to the "Covariate" box and specify any other output you want by clicking on the relevant button and checking the required option. Remember to declare to SPSS that your independent variable is categorical by clicking on the "Categorical" button and moving the variable name for your age categories to the "Categorical Covariates" box. Choose either the "first" or "last" age category to be your reference category so that you could obtain odds ratios of the other two categories in reference to the "reference category". After running the analysis, `EXP(B)` in the output table is the odds ratio.